# Need Rest API in Sitecore which can create, get, update , delete and publish items in sitecore without writing any code

Tags: sitecore-client, jss, sitecore-api, graphql

Is there any Rest API in Sitecore which can  create, get, update , delete and publish items in web instance and Solr without writing any code

Answer (score 3):

To create an item:

> URL: /item/{path}?database&language

Edit an item:

> URL: /item/{id}?database&language&version

Delete an item:

> URL: /item/{id}?database&language

Run a Sitecore search:

> URL: /item/search?term&pageSize&page&database&language&includeStandardTemplateFields&fields&sorting&facet

Run a stored Sitecore search:

> URL: /item/{id}/search?term&pageSize&page&database

For more details you can refer: [The RESTful API for the ItemService](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html)

Answer (score 0):

This article given by `Sitecore` contains almost all the `API` calls that can help you to perform all the operations.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

For the `publishing`, I found a good article you follow to publish an item on an API call.

https://www.nishtech.com/Blog/2019/July/SscPublish

Hope this will help you to start.

Thanks

Comment: I am able to login using (sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login) Api but not able to perform GET,Create,Logout operation.
 Getting 404 error. 
  
 Following below both links: 
 https://therelentlessfrontend.com/2018/02/11/sitecore-postman-a-quick-starter-guide/
 https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html

Comment: @RohitThakur Are you using Post for the Create?

Comment: Yes, even GET API is not working giving 404 error. When I login using(sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login), it's not creating .ASPXAUTH Cookies in postman according to this link..https://therelentlessfrontend.com/2018/02/11/sitecore-postman-a-quick-starter-guide/